# Wrong Resource values Android?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am working with an android project and having images in a library project for which i have created a JAR file.

The sequence of images in drawable folder in JAR file is as:

```
image1
image2
```

Now in my Application, The drawable folder has following sequence of images:

```
image3
image4
image1
```

Now if i want to pick the drawable from library code As R.drwable.image1, It picks image3 from my Applications Drawable folder and displays it.

In case if image1 is above  image3 it displays it image correctly.

I don't know why I am getting this problem of ordering. I am using android SDK revision 18. I have created a JAR using "FatJar" plugin in eclipse.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? we might spot the error then...

Comment: how are you calling the drawable ?

Comment: I am calling drawable as R.drawable.icon.

Comment: you should use librarypackagename.R.drawable.icon to reference image drawable from library project

Comment: @kjurkovic: It is a JAR file. Are you sure it will display image from JAR.

Comment: my experience says that using `"package name".R.drawble.image1` doesn't produce errors that sometimes `Android.R.drawable.image1` produce...try

Comment: if it is a jar and not a project in eclipse marked as library then i don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it picks image3 even though you chose `R.drawable.image1` ..

but try this

```
R.drwable.image1[1]
```

**update:**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: It picks image3. But if in library JAR if image1 is in second position and also in Application if image1 is at second position it displays it correct. I am surprised why it maps the image in orderly fashion.

Comment: I am picking up the image for the notification in the following way:Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, tickerText, when); here R.drawable.icon is selected as wrong.

Comment: so you have a file in your drawable folder called icon ?

Comment: yes, icon in drawable folder in Library and the same in Application drawable also.

Comment: i'm not sure why .. see my updated answer and try it better than yours method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36883/discussion-between-prabhjot-singh-and-ahmed-ekri)